# How to get all followers using instagram-private-api in Python?

Tags: python, api, instagram

The code I'm trying to write requires a list of all accounts following me, but the one I've written only gets precisely 193 out of 313:

```
followers = api.user_followers(api.authenticated_user_id, rank_token = Client.generate_uuid())
myFollowers = []

for i in range(len(followers['users'])):
    myFollowers.append(followers['users'][i]['username'])

print(myFollowers)
```

What can I change to get all the followers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch all users using "max_id" parameter.
Please check the code below.

```
myFollowers = []
next_max_id = "0"
while next_max_id != None :
    followers = api.user_followers(api.authenticated_user_id, rank_token = Client.generate_uuid(), max_id=next_max_id)
    next_max_id = followers.get('next_max_id')

    for i in range(len(followers['users'])):
        myFollowers.append(followers['users'][i]['username'])
print(myFollowers)
```

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to get rid of the earlier problem but a new one came saying: "instagram_private_api.errors.ClientError: Bad Request: unable to fetch followers" and "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request"... I think there is some error in the library code, because it runs fine for followees. I switched to instaloader library and that worked  perfectly.

Comment: Yes after some tries the client starts to give http 400 error. There is a limitation for the fetching followers.